# python performance tips -- loop involving comparisons

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I am new to python and am trying to learn more about how it works by successively optimizing chunks of naive code I have already written.

The following function involves a loop that performs operations on the elements of a list of list of floats only when the values of the data structure satisfy some condition. I was wondering if anyone could comment on (1) ways to improve the performance of this loop and (2) general features of the type of loop I'm describing that make it more or less suitable for different approaches to improving it. Below I've included a minimal version of the loop I'm working with.

Some notes on the variables used below:

```
#p is a small integer (say, p=10)
#index1 is an integer between 0 and p
#k is an integer between 0 and, say, kmax=100
#mat1 is a list of list of floats whose size is [kmax,p],
#    with all values initialized to 0.0. 
#    mat1 is changed by the loop below
#mat2 is a list of list of floats whose size is [kmax,p]
#    with all values initialized to -2e10. 
#    mat2 is changed by other parts of the program
```

Also, if it matters, in my code this is all part of a class, so there are "self." statements for the variables. I have read that local variables are handled better by python functions; how does this translate to class constructs?

```
def greatFunction(index1,k):                          
    index2 = index1
    for j in range(p):                        
        if (mat2[k][index2] > -1e10):         
            mat1[k][j] = mat1[k][j] + mat2[k][index1]*mat2[k][index2]
        index2 = index2 - 1
        if(index2 < 0):
            index2 = index2 + p
```

From what I have read I thought this would be a prime candidate for replacing the lists of lists with nparrays (in the class itself, not converting things in the function) and using masks to take care of the boolean conditions. However, the numpy version I wrote turned out to be slower than the vanilla python implementation above. Any help both speeding up the code but more importantly helping me understand why and how such loops can be replaced with a better construction would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: since  `(mat2[k][index2] > -1e10)` is always False, mat1=0 ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made clear that when I said "mat2 is changed by other parts of the program" that those changes can happen in between calls to greatFunction. Thus, in general, no, (mat2[k][index2] > -1e10) is not always False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `index2` goes from `index1` to `0` decreasing at steps of `1` and then *circulates* back to `p-1` and then starts decreasing again. This is basically `modulo operation` and thus could be simulated with [`np.mod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html) to give us `index2` as column indices at each iteration. Then, we index into the `k-th` row of `mat2` and use column indices from the previous step to get all elements needed for our purpose. These elements are compared with the threshold (`-1e10` in our case), giving us a mask, which is used to select elements from that row and set the corresponding ones into the output array `mat1` after scaling with `mat2[k][index1]`.

Since you are working with NumPy arrays, I am assuming you already have `mat1` and `mat2` converted to NumPy arrays with [`np.array()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html).

Also, as mentioned in the comments, if `mat2` has all its values initialized to `-2e10`, then `mat2[k][index2] > -1e10` would never be `true`, so in that particular case, `mat1` would keep its `zeros`. Thus, to generically explain how to vectorize such a case, I am assuming `mat2` to have random numbers instead. The implementation would look something like this -

```
# Get column indices corresponding to index2
col_idx = np.mod(np.arange(index1,index1-p,-1),p)

# Get all mat2 values with those column indices at kth row
mat2_val = mat2[k,col_idx]

# Mask of valid elements
mask = mat2_val > -1e10

# Set valid ones in mat1 with valid ones from mat2 
# after scaling with mat2[k][index1]
mat1[k][mask] = mat2[k][index1]*mat2_val[mask]
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to go through this, and for giving the generic vectorization since, as mentioned in response to the comment other part of the program can change mat2 away from its initial values.

Comment: Following up on the questions at the end of my post, would you say this sort of numpy implementation is the fastest or most efficient way to perform this sort of operation, or would other python approaches be better?

Comment: @David I would think the posted one to be very optimized implementation given that it uses just a function and rest is all slicing and indexing, so must be pretty fast. The only bottleneck would be conversion to NumPy array from the list of lists.

Comment: @David Also, it looks like you are only looping through `p` values, which is a small number. And you are changing only one row of values in `mat1`. Thus, the costs of preparing for vectorization might overshadow its benefits with actual computation. Aren't you looping through looping through rows of `mat2`?

Comment: Thanks again. Indeed, for small values of p the cost of preparing the vectorization is higher than the gains. By playing around with pre-initializing the calculation of the col_idx list (i.e. initializing the class with a list that stores col_idx for every possible value of index1) I could just about get the two implementations to take roughly equivalent amounts of time.